# Javascript on code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've been trying to run the code if any of the conditions get true. Its a dialog box which popups after postback created on Jquery Impromptu. I've tried to run the same code on a different project and its working fine however It doesn't show anything the condition met true

ASPX CODE

```
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/wufoo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-impromptu.2.6.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function confirmSubmit() {
        $.prompt('Are you sure you want to submit?'
            , {
                buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }
                , callback: confirmSubmitResult
            }
        );
        return false;
    }

    function confirmSubmitResult(v, m, f) {
        if (v) //post back if the user clicked OK

                $('#<%# btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
        }
    </script>
```

.CS CODE

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Header.DataBind();    
            TextBox2.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
            this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;


    }


    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string prompt = "<script>$(document).ready(function(){{$.prompt('{0}!');}});</script>";
        string message = string.Format(prompt, "This message is coming after postback");
  if (TextBox2.Text.Length == 0 || TextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "message", message);


    }
```

A little help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Is this an ajax request generated inside an update panel perhaps? If so, it's not firing because `document.ready` already fired.

Comment: I haven't used any Ajax update panel yet.